# Eloquent One-to-Many OrderBy

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm working with Eloquent on a One-to-Many relationship.

I want to order my Users by using their last post DateTime (created_at) but I can't figure out how to make this work.

Table Users :

```
 id | name 
 1  | John 
 2  | Doe
 3  | Foo
 4  | ...
```

Table Posts :

```
id | title  | body  | user_id | created_at 
1  | Title 1| Body1 | 1       | 2014-03-06 14:00:00
2  | Title 2| Body2 | 1       | 2014-03-04 14:00:00
3  | Title 3| Body3 | 2       | 2014-03-03 14:00:00
4  | Title 4| Body4 | 3       | 2014-03-05 14:00:00
```

Example of final output desired :

```
name | title   | created_at
John | Title 1 | 2014-03-06 14:00:00
Foo  | Title 4 | 2014-03-05 14:00:00
Doe  | Title 3 | 2014-03-03 14:00:00
```

The closer I could get was :

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function($query){
     $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

But this code extracts all the posts for each user and I just want the last one.

Can you help me please? Thanks.

**UPDATE** : I finally found what I was looking for : Retrieve users' last post and sort the users in ascending order (of this last post's timestamp). Feel free to improve this query!

```
$users = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('posts.id, posts.user_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at'))
    ->groupBy('posts.user_id')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id');
}))->get();
```

**Update:** You may try this:

```
$users = User::join('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
             ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
             ->groupBy('posts.user_id')
             ->select('users.*', 'posts.created_at as postTime')
             ->get();
```

I've only selected `created_at` from `posts` table but you may add more fields in `select` like:

```
->select('users.*', 'posts.created_at as postTime', 'posts.updated_at as postUpTime', 'posts.id as pid', 'posts.title')
```

Comment: This is half the answer. Now I get only the last_post data in my User collection. Now I want to sort my Users by their last_post timestamp. I really just don't know how. Is my structure wrong?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Result would be different (joined tables in one) if `$users->toArray()` used but you may use something like `$users->first()->posts->first()`.

Comment: Is there an easy way, with this query, to re-order again by using `posts.created_at`, but in an ascending order? In other words, to get Users' last post in ascending order.

Comment: Sorry! I don't think it's possible but I'll post if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will either have to use `usort()` which is a little bit more complicated, or you can use joins, but with that method, you'd also lose the way Eloquent sets up the relations.

Using `usort()`...

```
private function cmp($a, $b) 
{
    if($a->posts->created_at == $b->posts->created_at) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a->posts->created_at) < strtotime($b->posts->created_at)) ? -1 : 1;
}

$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->first();
}))->get();

$users = usort($users, array($this, 'cmp'));
```

Or if you would prefer to use joins, I think this should work for you.

```
$users = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(DB::raw('MAX(`posts`.`created_at`) AS `created_at`, `user_id`, `users`.*'))
    ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('posts.user_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->get();
```